# Python curses.flash() work only under certain conditions but theses doesn't seem to be documented

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

While programming with python curses I've came cross many unpredictable behaviors which I will not discuss here. But for now, among theses issues there is a particular one that bother me and understanding this might help for the other issues.

The following is working fine as long as I don't call ***stdscr.getkey()***. Indeed the screen is flashing every half-second. If I call ***stdscr.getkey()*** the screen flash once and only once. Pressing a key and moving forward into the loop doesn't change anything. Why ? I did not find any documentation on flash() and getkey() that could explain what is happening.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import curses

def test(stdscr):
    import time
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.curs_set(0)
    stdscr.keypad(True)
    
    while True:
        curses.flash()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        # ~ stdscr.getkey()
        
curses.wrapper(test)
```

Maybe some curses function alter some states in such a way that flash doesn't work anymore ? But how and why ?

Comment: `.getkey()` normally waits for a key to be pressed, so it blocks your `while` loop.  Surely you noticed that pressing a key allowed the next flash to take place?  You can call `stdscr.nodelay(True)` to make input non-blocking, although you might want to change the input call to `.getch()` (which returns -1 when no key has been pressed) instead of `.getkey()` (which raises an exception in that situation, which you'd have to catch).

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that I was aware of the purpose of the getkey(). And indeed, I'm pressing a key to move forward in the iteration. The thing is there is still no flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`flash`** in curses uses the *`flash`* capability in the terminal description.  For example, using `infocmp`, you may see something like this in the output:

```
flash=\E[?5h$<100/>\E?5l,
```

That tells the application to send an [escape sequence](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-5.1E65), wait 100 milliseconds, and send another escape sequence.  (Not all "xterm" wanna-be's implement `DECSCNM`; that defect is usually noted in the terminal database comments);

All screen updates in curses are *buffered*; **`flash`** is an update.  You can explicitly flush that buffer to the terminal using **[`refresh`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.refresh)**, or rely upon functions which read input (which as a side-effect will do a `refresh`).  If your program is prevented from writing to the terminal, you'll see no flashing.

Whether you call `getch` or `getkey`, that normally **blocks** until you press a key.  You can use [timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.timeout), [nodelay](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.nodelay), etc., which are mentioned in the documentation.

By the way, `time.sleep` will interfere with the refresh.  Use [`napms`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.napms).

For example:

```
> diff -u foo.orig foo
--- foo.orig    2022-07-20 03:53:05.000000000 -0400
+++ foo 2022-07-20 03:56:18.833794715 -0400
@@ -8,10 +8,14 @@
     curses.cbreak()
     curses.curs_set(0)
     stdscr.keypad(True)
-    
+    stdscr.nodelay(1)
+
     while True:
         curses.flash()
-        time.sleep(0.5)
-        # ~ stdscr.getkey()
-        
+        curses.napms(500)
+        try:
+            stdscr.getkey()
+        except curses.error:
+            pass
+
 curses.wrapper(test)
```

Further reading:

- [Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)
- [beep, flash - curses bell and screen flash routines](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_beep.3x.html)
- [Reading characters (getch)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters)

OP comments that calling [use_default_colors](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/default_colors.3x.html) helps with `flash`.  That depends (as does `DECSCNM`) upon the terminal, but the reason why it would make a difference is because the python [curses wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper) calls `start_color`, which causes ncurses to try to color the terminal with white-on-black.  Calling `use_default_colors` partly cancels that, because there are no explicit colors used in the script, so that you'll see only the terminal's default colors.  If the terminal emulator shows `DECSCNM` only when using the default (uncolored) configuration, then that's what you'd get for a "working" flash.

As far as ncurses is concerned, "flash" is separate from the details of *color* and *refresh* (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/697db0c3d1599a7c5aa1c192d683b2a185fcd80f/ncurses/base/lib_flash.c#L61)).  It only happens to rely upon the buffer-flushing done in a refresh.

Comment: Well it won't do either :

https://gist.github.com/DenisSalem/2972a9940f2dccc7ab133e0db69860aa

Without getkey() and with a refresh(), it flash once and only once. Refreshing before flashing bring no flash at all. I don't get when I'm supposed to refresh and when I'm not supposed to.

Comment: Just tested your example in your edited reply. Doesn't work either : Flash once ...

The python and ncurses version are :

curses.ncurses_version(major=6, minor=2, patch=20200212)
python3.8.10

Comment: Actually, I'm starting to believe the issue comes from the terminal emulator itself...

It doesn't work with terminator, it doesn't work with the geany internal terminal emulator but it DOES work with konsole ...

The question is now what settings and possible implementations differences are involved.

Comment: Some terminal emulators don't implement the escape sequence (the most common problem with *flash*).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it might not be perfect but I believe I came accross something that look like a possible solution.

By testing the snippet of code on multiple terminal emulator, like terminator that support transparency I noticed that calling refresh() or getkey() was wipping the background with a new color.

When it happens the flash() doesn't operate anymore. I'm not sure why this happening (i.e, why refresh(), getch() and getkey() change the color settings) but here we are.

So a working and portable code (assuming visual bell is enabled) would look like this I guess :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import curses

def test(stdscr):
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.curs_set(0)
    stdscr.keypad(True)
    stdscr.nodelay(1)
    curses.use_default_colors()
    while True:
        curses.flash()

        curses.napms(500)
        try:
            stdscr.getkey()
            break
        except curses.error:
            pass
            
curses.wrapper(test)
```

This particular line does the trick

```
    curses.use_default_colors()
```

Any further explanation are welcomes !

**EDIT : See Thomas Dickey answer for more details**